# Custom field for new order new customer

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

I want to add 'Business name' field to billing and shipping address form in creating new customer while creating new order from admin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? What is the problem?

Roadmap:

- Create a setup script
- add an attribute for customer_address

Maybe you have to add the field manually to the form template